# Run external executable in JAR file

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, bash, jar

I'm running an external executable in my Java application using bash script (I'm in linux). I have a function `runCommand(String command)` that gets a string as if I'm running it in terminal and nicely runs the command.

My command contains absolute path, and is something like:

`home\username\execfolder\exec -f home\username\execfolder\file.txt`

Everything is fine. But now I want to create an execrable JAR file that self-contains all such external exec files so I can run it everywhere. I'm in Eclipse IDE, and I did the following:

- I created a `lib` folder in my project and copied all those files in `home\username\execfolder` inside. Like the figure below.
- go to `project properties -> Java built-path -> Source -> Add folder` and added `lib` folder.
- I simply changed the command string in my code to `.\exec -f file.txt` assuming they should be visible.
- I create an executable jar with 'export' option.

[image]

But when running the jar, it complaints exec does not exists. How should I fix it? What is wrong in my steps?

The problem is that after these steps, I don't see any `lib` folder inside the jar file. The `exec` file is simply on the main page, not inside any lib. That's why I use `.\exec` instead of `\lib\exec`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be .\lib\exec -f file.txt ?

Comment: I think I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: The problem is that using my steps, I don't see any `lib` folder inside the jar file. The exec file is simply on the main page, not inside any lib. That's why I use `.\exec`